# How do I randomly switch something every week in PHP?

Tags: php

I have three divs and want them to switch out for another once a week.

Comment: Read [http://stackoverflow.com/about](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Show us what you've tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: please post the code that's not working for you.

Comment: Come in early on Monday morning and swap the code!

Comment: Are you totally sure this has not yet been asked and answered before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that accomplishes what Julian below talked about:

```
  $woy = date('W', time());

switch($woy % 3)
{
    case 0: echo 'div 1';
    case 1: echo 'div 2';
    case 2: echo 'div 3';
}
```

Or something like this..

```
$w = ceil(date('d', time())/7);

    if ($w == 1 || $w == 4)
    {
     //echo div 1...
    }
    elseif ($w == 2)
    {
     //echo div 2....
    }
    elseif ($w == 3)
    {
     //echo div 3....
    }
```

Comment: @Jon: propose something less bulky and then come back with real confidence

Comment: Why would I suggest something less bulky when there is already an answer here that does. And don't worry, I am plenty confident that this is bulky. (and why use the 'day of month' instead of just using the week of month?  It would lead to errors because not every month starts on a monday. ^^)

Comment: @khanahk don't get irritated, Jon has a valid point, when encountering this kind of conditions, you should use `switch()`.

Comment: The previous answer is the proposal of an idea; not the full code to accomplish it. `switch()` would be more refactored, yes.

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at php's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you'll see that you can have it return the week number for the year.

```
date('W');
```

From there, use the modulus operator (`date('W') % 3`) to determine which `div` to show. If it is 0, show the first div, if it is 1, show the second, and if it is 2, show the third.

Answer (score 0):

1) Store when you switched them out and compare that date to the current date and if difference is 7 then change to different div to display

or

2) Pick a day e.g. Monday and if date is Monday then change the div to display

You may have to store/choose how you want to change the order of divs unless you are randomizing the order